# c# File.WriteAllText as administrator

Tags: c#, file, file-access

Do we need Administrator rights to write to a file using `File.WriteAllText`? I get `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` when I try to call it.

Here is my code:

```
        public void JsonHashTagWrite(string vrednost, string path)
        {
            string json = File.ReadAllText(path);
            dynamic jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
            jsonObj["envVariablesConditions"]["initEnvVariables"][26]["value"] = "#" + vrednost;
            string output = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj, 
            Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
            File.WriteAllText(path, output);
        }
```

Comment: Sounds like you've already found the solution then :)

Comment: You don't need administrator rights to open a file. You need the permission to read the file, either directly on your user or via a group. Edit: same goes for writing to the file (with write permission).

Answer (score -3):

Visual Studio needs administrator rights.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).